# Accessing OneDrive as a StorageFolder from the local storage

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, local-storage, windows-8.1, onedrive

I have been developing one Windows Store app for Win 8.1. Is there a way to access the user's OneDrive which is already synced on the hard drive? I need to access it as a StorageFolder. Similarly to KnownFolders and all the libraries. The reason behind that is that I am doing something like a gallery app that displays thumbnails of videos and pictures. When the users decides the app shows the media in full size and if it is a video, it is played. The app counts on the fact that OneDrive automatically syncs all the data, so it does need to be retrieved via the Live SDK API. If I use REST, it will be just too slow. Do you know if there is a way to achieve the mentioned approach effectively or maybe some alternative?

I have been researching extensively, but with no avail.

Thank you!

All the best,
Rosko

Comment: Use the `FolderPicker` and allow the user to pick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nate mentioned, you gain access to the folder through the FolderPicker API. There's no direct way to obtain the StorageFolder for that location.

Once you get that StorageFolder and enumerate contents, the extra piece you want to know about is the StorageFile.isAvailable API, as well as StorageFile.getThumbnailAsync/getScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync. The isAvailable flag is what tells you whether a file has actually been downloaded/synced, because the user might have indicated "online only" for any files.

I write about this a bit in Chapter 11 of my free ebook [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2) (page 575, pages 593-597), including a table about how OneDrive availability works with metered networks. This includes using thumbnails.

There's also a talk from //build 2013 on this, "What New in Working with Files" by Marc Wautier, http://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2013/2-119. Should answer your OneDrive questions.